# Eclipse JDT core Java runtime error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, runtimeexception, eclipse-jdt

I could not find any helping document regarding this error hence I am posting this question.

I am trying to use locally built Eclipse JDT core jar in my project. I followed the flowing steps.

1. Created an eclipse workspace as described in [Link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Platform_SDK_Provisioning)
2. Built `eclipse.jdt.core` using the `mvn -P build-individual-bundles package`
3. Added the resulting **jar** file that is created in the `target` folder to my project (i.e., `project A`) as a maven dependency.

After the above steps, I could successfully compile project A and now it gives me the following runtime error.

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.SubMonitor.split(I)Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/SubMonitor;
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:820)
    at utils.JavaASTUtil.parseSource(JavaASTUtil.java:87)
    at change.CFile.<init>(CFile.java:32)
    at change.RevisionAnalyzer.buildGitModifiedFiles(RevisionAnalyzer.java:310)
    at change.RevisionAnalyzer.analyzeGit(RevisionAnalyzer.java:130)
    at change.ChangeAnalyzer.analyzeGit(ChangeAnalyzer.java:243)
    at change.ChangeAnalyzer.analyzeGit(ChangeAnalyzer.java:228)
    at main.MainChangeAnalyzer$2.run(MainChangeAnalyzer.java:99)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

pom.xml of the project is given below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>AtomicASTChangeMining</groupId>
    <artifactId>AtomicASTChangeMining</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-maven-repo</id>
            <url>file:///Users/xx/Documents/Research_Topic_2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!--Below is the locally built jdt core jar -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0-v20140318-2214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.resources</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0.v20150423-0755</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0-v20140606-1445</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Does anybody have any idea about the runtime error?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do experiments on org.eclipse.core version. You might need to upgrade the version of `org.eclipse.birt.runtime`. Select the version that contains the method SubMonitor.split().

Answer (score 2):

`org.eclipse.core.runtime.SubMonitor` is actually in the `org.eclipse.equinox.common` plug-in.

According to the Javadoc the `split` methods were added to `SubMonitor` in version 3.8 of org.eclipse.equinox.common. This corresponds to Eclipse release 4.6.